# What steps should I take after kitty litter has been washed down the drain?

Tags: plumbing, bathtub, drainage

A relative tried to do me a "favor" and clean out the bathtub where a kitty box had been temporarily stored.  I guess 2-3 pounds of clumping litter were washed down the drain.  It doesn't appear to be clogged (lucky!), but I was wondering if there are any steps I can take to prevent any settled litter from causing future blockages.

I have municipal water if that makes a difference.

Comment: It's so sad people think that whatever they don't know how to deal with should be flushed into toilet.

Comment: @sharptooth: my mother will actually take the hair and crud that accumulates on the bathtub drain filter and flush it down the toilet. It's like she thinks the toilet drain goes to an entirely different (and magical) place than all the other drains in the house.

Comment: I read a blogger once that complained about how some politician wanted us to start drinking the same water that the dinosaurs went the bathroom in.

Comment: Poor lye in the drain. I wash my litter box in the tub all the time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it rinsed down the drain and hasn't clogged yet then you're in fairly good shape.  Clumping litter definitely can be saturated and breaks down.  I'm assuming this is some sort of clay based litter (I use a pine based product myself) with fairly small granules and not a lot of stone.

Also I'm presuming that you haven't been flushing the line out with water continuously, and so if any clumping was going to occur, it would have.

If you have access to any of the traps I would go ahead and put a bucket underneath and open them up just to be certain.

If you don't have access then you either continue to flush the line or you could use a plumber's snake (a home version is a great investment) to disturb any settled litter possibly while flushing.

Not a magic bullet, but probably a measured response.